Quais as variantes de pronuncia da letra "r" imediatamente após uma vogal, no Brasil e em Portugal?
Em minha região no Brasil (Rio de Janeiro), há uma pronuncia típica do "r" em palavras como terceira, esquerda, horta, sorte, etc. A minha pergunta é sobre as variantes de pronuncia do som do r, imediatamente após e na mesma sílaba que uma vogal (forte, terceira, etc). Ouço com frequência, pelo menos mais duas variantes.  Quais são elas? Como podemos representá-las em IPA ? (uma gravação seria muito bom)  Como elas se distribuem em termos geográficos?
Para facilitar o entendimento da pergunta, vou tentar descrever as três variantes que ouço.

A pronuncia do carioca, que seria algo como "carrta", "sorrte" onde ocorre um ronco no palato mole e adjacências.
A pronuncia do paulista, que soa mesmo como "carta" e "sorte", onde ocorre uma leve vibração no palato duro.
A pronuncia do mineiro do interior, que não sei como descrever.

Não sei se existem outras formas de pronuncia, e isso faz parte da pergunta.

Em princípio esta tabela tem todos os elementos necessários.

Essa tabela nada diz em relação à pergunta.

https://grad.letras.ufmg.br/arquivos/monitoria/Aula%2002%20apoio.pdf  Veja: róticos.

Se a (3) é semelhante ao "r" americano (como em "car"), é a retroflexa, [ɹ], "(Encurvamento da língua em direção ao palato duro)" — fonte: pdf 'linkado' no comentário acima.

Fiz uma primeira pesquisa em Cunha e Cintra que referem 3 formas do r:

[r] português normal de Portugal e do Brasil: caro, cores, dar
[r̄] português normal de várias regiões de Portugal, do Rio Grande do Sul e outras regiões do Brasil: roda, carro
[R] português normal de Portugal (principalmente de Lisboa), do Rio de Janeiro e de várias zonas costeiras do Brasil: roda. carro

Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo, Lisboa, 2015, p. 731-2)

Quanto à posição destas consoantes  relativamente às vogais:

Só em posição intervocálica é possível encontrar as dezenove consoantes portuguesas que acabamos de descrever e classificar. Noutras posições, o número de consoantes possíveis reduz-se sensivelmente.
Assim, em posição inicial de palavra, além das consoantes oclusivas e fricativas, (...) das vibrantes, o [r] ou o [r̄]
(...)
Em posição final de sílaba ou de palavra, só se encontram normalmente as consoantes:
(...)
b) r, a que corresponde, nas pronúncias normais de Portugal e do Brasil, o [r] simples apical, algumas vezes perdido na pronúncia popular brasileira, quando em final absoluta;



Como podemos representá-las em IPA?

Boa pergunta, ainda não tentei fazer a correspondência com as tabelas do IPA modernas. Mas também não tentei pesquisar fontes mais recentes e especializadas.

Eu não me referi aos sons da letra r.  A minha pergunta é sobre o som de r, imediatamente após e na mesma sílaba que uma vogal (sorte, forte, horta, terceira).  Também inclui a distribuição geográfica de cada uma e a representação em IPA ou uma gravação do som, caso contrário não saberemos a que formas de pronúncia você se refere.
